# What is the specific manifest entry i have to do to make my application a video Player

Tags: android, audio, video, video-streaming, audio-streaming

i made a video player application in android.
now from file explorer if anybody wants to open a video , i want my application name to be there to choose from the list of video player applications , to play that video.

what is the specific menifest entry i have to do to make my application a video Player to play multimedia video  files

Answer (score 0):

You need to define Intent Filetrs for your app, in this way android will register your app for specific Intents you want, so next time when user click any Item, android will open a Picker to choose specific apps which can handle those Intents, read here.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html, for your case particularly you have define following under your manifiest activity handling playing.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```